RSTP and MAC addresses: how should I ensure that the bridge switch has the lowest MAC?
I'm very confused about RSTP; what I've read states that the bridge is selected by either lowest priority (set in the switch configuration) or by lowest MAC.  Does that mean that I have to "hand-select" switches to find the one with the lowest MAC? How do I ensure that the switch that I want to be bridge has the lowest MAC address?  I thought MAC addresses were hard-coded into devices and couldn't be changed.

Basically, you set the lowest priority on the one you want to be the root, and the second lowest priority on the one for the alternate root.
The MAC address is a tie breaker. If you do not set the priority on any switches, then, yes, the lowest MAC address wins, and that may be the oldest switch in the network (not ideal in most cases).
Cisco has a default priority of 32768 on its switches, There is a command to set the root and the secondary root. You could also just set the root priority to 0 and the secondary root to 4096. Either way, the root and secondary root end up with priorities lower than the default.

Thanks for this, very clear!  Just to be even more clear: a switch does NOT include its own MAC address to calculate a BPDU if it has been assigned a priority in its configuration?  It's the absence of a priority value that caused the MAC to be used?  Do I have that correct, or even close?

Not exactly. The priority is prepended to the MAC address, so if the priorities are the same, then the MAC address is what decides. That is why you should always pick the proper root and set its priority.
